# login php script not allowing login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have created a log in system however when i log in it say the email or password are incorrect even though it's a test user and the details are correct. Maybe it doesn't match the database, I have check over and over again. I can't seem to find the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
header("Location: index-user.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$email = trim($email);
$upass = trim($upass);

$res=mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row

if($count == 1 && $row['user_pass']==md5($upass))
{
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_id'];
    header("Location: index-user.php");
}
else
{
    ?>
<script>alert('Email or password invalid.');</script>
    <?php
}

}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input class="loginmodal-input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<input class="loginmodal-input" type="password" name="upass" placeholder="Password" required>
<button type="submit" name="btn-login" id="login-btn" class="login btn-block loginmodal-submit">Login</button>
<button class="login-btn-2 btn btn-lg btn-block" type="button" aria-label="Close" value="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel</button>
```

**MySQL Info:**
user_id
user_name
user_email
user_pass

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: Have you debugged to see where it hangs up? Why not md5 (md5 really shouldn't be used for password hashing anymore) the password and send it with the username to validate the user?

Comment: I'm new to this. and i've been trying to use PDO, takes time to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in this line:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
```

results `True` if the `$_SESSION['user']` is set, not if it's empty: `isset` return boolean value, set to `True` if the variable is set, to `False` otherwise. An ampty string is evaluated as `False`. So, when `$_SESSION['user']` is not set, the code evaluate `if( False != False )`.

Furthermore, you have to end the php script after calling `header("Location")`:

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) )
{
    header( "Location: index-user.php" );
    die();
}

(...)
```

Comment: Now it won't load anything, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: You redirect on same page? or `index-user.php` redirect to this page?

Comment: If the user is not set AND we are NOT on index-user.php, DO the redirect to index-user.php. That's if the code is shared between pages.

Comment: No, i'm redirecting to a different page after login. (index-user.php)

Comment: I've replicate your code on my machine and the first redirection works. Try to redirect to a non-existing page: if you obtain a 404 error code the problem is not in the code above.

Comment: nor does it display an error if and incorrect email and pass are entered. it seems like it merely refreshes the page.

Comment: You want redirect to `index-user.php` if the `$_SESSION['user']` is set or if it is unset? my code redirects if user is NOT set. Otherwise you have to write `isset( $_SESSION['user'] )`

Comment: In addiction, please note that `isset` returns `True` when the variable is set but empty

Comment: I need to redirect if the user is set. so something wrong here `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101628/discussion-between-fusion3k-and-about-leros).